# Non-symmetric positive definite matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a positive definite matrix with $x^TAx>0$ $\forall x\neq 0$. $A$ is invertible.

In our script it is stated that a **symmetric** matrix $A$ with only positive eigenvalues is called positive definite ($\lambda_i>0$). For every non-symmetric $x^TAx>0$ is the definition for positive definite.
For a symmetric matrix this proof seems easy, because an invertible matrix A has:
$$
\det(A)\neq 0
$$
and
$$
\det(A)=\Pi_{i=1}^n\lambda_i
$$
$\implies$ Because every eigenvalue is $>0\implies\det(A)\neq 0$ thus $A$ is invertible.

First of all, is this proof true correct?

Second, how do you proof this for any matrix $A$ (whether symmetric or non-symmetric)?

Comment: Nothing fancy is needed. If $A$ is singular, there is a nonzero vector $x$ with $Ax=0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin That seems a lot easier than I thought it would be! Thank you.